# Installing Custom Android Kernel in Sony Xperia NXT series (U, Sola, P, S)

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, android-source

I have a Sony Xperia P. It runs on 6_0_B_1_564 Kernel and Andriod 2.3.7. I have compiled a custom kernel from the source. I changed the extraversion etc. I have got the zImage. How do I install it  on my phone?

I have already tried Anykernel.zip method. When I try to install it using Clockworkmod, I get-

```
--Installing: /sdcard/new_kernel.zip
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Installing update...
AnyKernel Updater by Koush.
Extracting System Files...
Extracting Kernel files...
Changing device name...
Done!

Install from sdcard complete.
```

But when I start the phone its the same old kernel

When I when through the contents of the zip file, I found that there is no boot.img in it.

Can I flash the kernel using Fastboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did manage to install the custom kernel. Guess the procedure will work for all the Sony Xperia NXT series phones (Xperia U, Sola, P, S). This is how I did it -

1. Download the Stock Kernel from the following links -

   [Sony Xperia U](http://d-h.st/6q1)

   [Sony Xperia Sola](http://d-h.st/aoY)

   [Sony Xperia P](http://d-h.st/Gaa)

   [Sony Xperia S](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&drKey=1359&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D1635582&v=1&libid=1343847870568&out=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2Fxps_ask_1&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Fp%3D16742112&title=%5BKERNEL%5D%5BXperia%20S%5D%20Advanced%20Stock%20Kernel%20with%20Recovery%20%5BRel%3Av01%5D%5BDt%3A05%2FMAY%5D%20-%20xda-developers&txt=%3Cb%3E%5BXperia%20S%5D%20Advanced%20Stock%20Kernel%20%28FW%3A%20.62%2F.67%2F.73%20%29%3C%2Fb%3E&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13438478860922)

   These will be ELF format.
2. Download the Image generation script from [here](http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/tools/image_generation_script_for_Xperia_smartphones.zip).
3. Unpack the Stock Kernel.

   `7z e kernel.elf`

   This yields three files -

   `0 - Kernel`

   `1 - RAMDisk`

   `2 - Resource Power Manager (only for Xperia S)`
4. Replace the kernel with out custom compiled kernel(`zImage`). Note that `zImage` is renamed  to `0`. Since we intend to change only the kernel, keep the RAMDisk and Resource Power Manager(if any) as it is.
5. Generate the Kernel Image using the Script downloaded before

   For Xperia U, Sola and P -

   `python mkelf.py -o new_kernel.elf 0@0x00200000 1@0x01200000,ramdisk`

   For Xperia S -

   `python mkelf.py -o new_kernel.elf 0@0x40208000 1@0x41200000,ramdisk 2@0x20000,rpm`

   This generates a new kernel `new_kernel.elf`
6. Reboot the phone into Fastboot mode by holding the Volume-Up button and then pressing the Power button in switched off state.
7. Flash the new kernel

   `android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/fastboot -i 0x0fce flash boot new_kernel.elf`

   Reboot the phone.

   `android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/fastboot -i 0x0fce reboot`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the anykernel updater, the following happens.

> updater-script runs and extract the boot.img from your current ROM. It
>   unpacks the boot.img into kernel and ramdisk. It repacks newboot.img
>   with the new kernel and the same ramdisk. It flashes the newly created
>   boot image.

Now, your boot.img is the same as your old kernel's. Only your zImage has changed.

Now it is possible that the script is incompatible with your existing kernel.

Check `uname -a` from the console using something like Terminal Emulator to confirm kernel version with timestamp. Check the timestamp to see if the new zImage is in place.

Comment: `Linux localhost 2.6.35.7+ #1 SMP PREEMT Thu Apr 12 11:16:24 2012 armv71 GNU/Limux` While customizing the kernel I had changed the extraversion to .7-anirudh-mod

Comment: I recommend, you extract the RamDisk from an existing kernel and couple your compiled zImage with it. The anykernel script doesn't work with kernels which haven't been made to support that modular approach.

Comment: Can you please give a lead on how to go about it?

Comment: after coupling the zImage with the Ramdisk, how do I install in?

Comment: A set of RamDisks is [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1312692) and instructions are [here](http://madteam.co/news/2012/02/how-to-build-a-custom-android-kernel-for-your-device/). After coupling it, you will get a new archive named zImage. Extract any existing kernel's CWM zip, replace the zImage and zip it up again.

Comment: Do you know where I can find unpackbootimg and mkbootimg binaries for 32 bit linux?

Comment: In the link which you told me, there is no Randisk for Xperia P. Will it be ok I use Ramdisk for Arc S?

Comment: Or can I use the Ramdisk from the CWM's backup?

Comment: [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=229872&d=1253485580). You can use the RamDisk from your CWM backup. For steps on how to build, use the IRC channel for help.